# who to start as black in stockfish python

Tags: python, python-chess, stockfish

I'm trying to start the Stockfish module in Python as the black player instead of the default white. I've been looking for parameters or other information on how to do this, but haven't been able to find anything that works. Can you please help me figure out how to start Stockfish as black in Python?

Comment: As an aside, it's probably not possible to start evaluation as black if the board position isn't legal for it to be black's turn.

Answer (score 1):

The [module](https://pypi.org/project/stockfish/) has `set_fen_position` method. You can use this to set stockfish to play as black.

Take the start fen:

```
fen = "rnbqkbnr/pppp1ppp/4p3/8/4P3/8/PPPP1PPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 2"
```

Change the side to move from `w` to `b`.

```
fen_b = "rnbqkbnr/pppp1ppp/4p3/8/4P3/8/PPPP1PPP/RNBQKBNR b KQkq - 0 2"
```

Finally use this fen in the method.

```
stockfish.set_fen_position(fen_b)
```